# jquery remove all div but 1 not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove all div elements while only keeping one to show http://jsfiddle.net/m5pt4kxa/

I tried all of these but none work , they remove everything and don't show the #mfloverview

```
$('#body_home div:not(#mfloverview)').remove();
$('#body_home div').not('#mfloverview').remove();
$('div').not('#mfloverview').remove();
```

Here is the HTML

```
<body id="body_home">
  <div id="home" class="pagebody">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div id="mfloverview"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `#myfloverview` is the child of main div `#home`. It will remove everything within the parent.

Comment: $("div > *:not(#mfloverview)").remove();   This worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selections select all `div` elements that don't have `#mfloverview`. This includes `#home`. Your code removes that element and everything inside and finishes.

Make your selection a little more particular:

```
$('#body_home #home div').not('#mfloverview').remove();
```

So the selected `<div>` elements must be a descendant of `#home`, which must be a descendant of `#body_home`

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m5pt4kxa/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you target all divs other than `#mfloverview`, you are targeting its parent divs also which case it also to be removed as its a child in it.

Try removing the divs inside `#home` but not `#mfloverview` like the code below.

```js
$('#home div').not('#mfloverview').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="body_home">
  <div id="home" class="pagebody">
    <div>s</div>
    <div>d</div>
    <div>f</div>
    <div id="mfloverview">g</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#body_home div").not(document.getElementByid('mfloverview')).remove()
```

Comment: First try to comment why you answer will help the OP, and the second don't mix Jquery and Javascript, sometimes the OP could get Confuse.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#home').find(":not(#mfloverview)").remove();
```

or

```
$('div').find(":not(#mfloverview)").remove();
```